# Bind dynamically created element to complex mvc model in view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a very huge form in my application with a lot of different inputs and a lot of lists in my model. So i will try to add/delete the lists without sending the complete model to the server.

I tried several ways now but i don´t find a clean way. You can imagine my model like:

```
public class EditSomething
{
    public string name { get; set;}

    public List<something> somethingList { get; set;}

    // a lot other fields...

    public EditSomething(EditSomethingFromDatabase editSomethingFromDatabase)
    {
        name = editSomethingFromDatabase.Name;
        somethingList = new List<SomethingModel>();
        foreach(var something in editSomethingFromDatabase.Something)  
        {
            somethingList.Add(new SomethingModel(editSomethingFromDatabase.Something));
        }
    }
}
```

The other model looks similar but without lists.

In the view i have a table for the model:

```
    <h2>Something</h2> 
    <div id="SomethingDiv">
        <table id="SomethingTable">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>@Html.Label("SomethingName")</th>
                    <th>@Html.Label("SomethingID")</th>
                                                <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="SomethingTableBody">

                @Html.EditorFor(x => x.somethingList)

            </tbody>
        </table>
        <p>
            <input type="button" name="addSomething" value="Add Something" id="AddSomething">
        </p>
    </div>
```

the jquery of the addSomething is:

```
  $('#AddSomething').click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("AddSomething", "SomethingModels")',
            data: { tableSize: $('#SomethingTable tr').length },
            cache: false,
            success: function (html) { $('#SomethingTable tr:last').after(html); }
        });
```

The controller method AddSomething is:

```
public ActionResult AddSomething (int tableSize)
{
    SomethingModel something= new SomethingModel(null, (-2) * (tableSize + 1));
    return PartialView(""~/Views/EditorTemplates/EditSomethingModel.cshtml"", something);
}
```

And at least i have a editor template in EditorTemplates as for editorfor and partialview. This have the important informations i want to send to the server:

```
@model SomethingModel
<tr>@TextBoxFor(m=>m.SomethingName)<td>
```

@TextBoxFor(m=>m.SomethingID)

So the problem now is, that the submit of the first view only post the `SomethingModel` to the server who already existed while opening the view but the new SomethingModel from the `AddMutation` method aren´t in the post. Someone an idea to fix this?

Edit: Changed the path to the editor template so i only need one view for the `EditorFor` and `PartialView`.

Edit2: To solve the main problem i created a view as following and use it as partial view. Now the data is send to the server correctlly. Only the validation on client side is still not working:

```
@model SomethingModel
    <tr>@TextBoxFor(m=>m.SomethingName, new{Name="somethingList["+ViewBag.ListId+"].SomethingName")<span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="somethingList[@ViewBag.ListId].SomethingName" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span><td>
<tr>@TextBoxFor(m=>m.SomethingID, new{Name="somethingList["+ViewBag.ListId+"].SomethingID")<span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="somethingList[@ViewBag.ListId].SomethingID" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span><td>
</tr>
```

In the `AddSomething` method i added the `ViewBag.ListId` with the id of the next element in the list.

Comment: I've altered my answer with the change you need to make to get unobtrusive validation to work with your new fields after the ajax callback.

Comment: Yes is see. But you need to remove all validations from the form you want to submit. This will work: var table = `$('#SomethingForm').removeData("validator").removeData("unobtrusiveValidation");
                    $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(table);` Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems a reasonable enough approach, but You've not shown your EditorTemplate, so I'm going to assume its something like:

```
@model List<something>

@for(int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{
   <tr>
     <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m[i].Id) @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].Id)</td>
     <td>@Html.EditorFor(m => m[i].Name)</td>
   </tr>
}
```

Your ajax method should return the HTML of a row - and this is important... the form fields need to be named 1 above the last one in the table.

So when you view the rendered source of your table (before adding any new fields it might look like:

```
...
<tbody>
   <tr>
     <td>1 <input type="hidden" name="something[0].Id" value="1"/></td>
     <td><input type="text" name="something[0].Name" value="somename" /></td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

You need to ensure the html returned by the ajax method for your new row is:

```
   <tr>
     <td>2 <input type="hidden" name="something[1].Id" value="2"/></td>
     <td><input type="text" name="something[1].Name" value="somenewname" /></td>
   </tr>
```

ie. the number inside the brackets is the next index for the items in something. If there is a gap in the indexes (or they overlap) then the new items will not get parsed.

EDIT - to get client side validation to work for the new fields alter your jquery ajax success callback as follows:

```
$('#AddSomething').click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("AddSomething", "SomethingModels")',
        data: { tableSize: $('#SomethingTable tr').length },
        cache: false,
        success: function (html) { 
            $('#SomethingTable tr:last').after(html);
            $.validator.unobtrusive.parse('#SomethingTable');
        }
    });
```

Comment: I changed the code in my question. The last code sample is the editor template. I use `EditorFor` to show every element from the somethingList. The mvc helper automatically crated a viw for each item in the list so you don´t need to use a loop.
Also my ajax method returned the HTML of a row, but your right, it don´t use the numeration from the list. Instead of `<td><input type="text" name="something[0].Name" value="somename" /></td>` i only get it created as `<td><input type="text" name="Name" value="somename" /></td>`. So thank you for that hind, i will check how i can change this.

Comment: @James if you have a gap on the indexes, lets say because you have a minus button to remove the dynamic html, how can I still parse the entire collection?

Comment: @Zinov You'd need some javascript to reindex all the fields later than the one removed. You can't leave gaps in the client side field indexes or they will not get parsed on postback. Eg `<input type='button' value='Remove' onClick='removeRow(0)' />` and then define a javascript function that removes the row, and goes through the collection of rows with a higher index - replacing all instances of [rowindex] with [rowindex -1]